# Yet another "unmet peer dependency" question

Tags: firebase, yarnpkg

I still don't understand this, despite reading many SO questions and docs. So if this is really a dup, please feel free to point me to anywhere that will explain it.

After adding firebase to my Vue.js project using yarn, I get lots of:

```
warning "firebase > @firebase/database@0.3.12" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore@1.0.4" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions@0.3.7" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/messaging@0.3.11" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage@0.2.8" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/auth > @firebase/auth-types@0.5.2" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
```

I do already have @firebase/app-types@0.3.4 installed, as a dependency (listed in my yarn.lock but not in package.json).
I can resolve these errors by manually doing `yarn add @firebase/app-types` but I don't see why I need to do that -- I don't ever call anything from @firebase/app-types directly in my app. If firebase depends on it, and it's already installed, why do I get this error? I guess I don't really understand what an unmet "peer dependency" really means. Is this really a problem in firebase (@5.8.4) itself?

I've read through https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-types/, which says "Peer dependencies are a special type of dependency that would only ever come up if you were publishing your own package." but clearly it's coming up for me, despite not publishing my own package -- I'm working on an app. I'd appreciate any light shed on this topic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "peer dependency" is best understood as a soft dependency link between a plugin and the software to which it adds functionality.

If every plugin specified a hard dependency on the main software, then you'd be in versioning hell (worse than now).

A "peer dependency" allows a firebase plugin (for example) to hint at which version of firebase it works with by naming a peer dependency.

They are so-called because neither party is the "owner" of the relationship, it's a symbiosis, the package with the extra features only woks with a finite range of versions of the "host" package.

> I can resolve these errors by manually doing yarn add @firebase/app-types but I don't see why I need to do that -- I don't ever call anything from @firebase/app-types directly in my app.

Because the "peer dependency" is a hint, nothing will install those dependencies for you, they are more like suggestions. Unfortunately it's up to you to know if you need that thing or not, and whether that warning makes sense.

You may be a victim of this bug https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4850 which is referencing an issue with the `app-types` package being required *also* in non-TypeScript packages.

You didn't include a language tag on your post so it's not possible to know whether you are using JavaScript or TypeScript, but if you are using TypeScript you should probably add that package as a development dependency.

That's the meaning of a peer dependency, the tooling cannot know for sure if you need that thing, and not having met all your dependents optional (peer) dependencies might be breaking something, hence the `[warning]`.

You may want to read https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1207#issuecomment-424804228 and note that there's no black and white answer to this, it seems to be highly subjective.

Comment: Thanks! I still have no true idea whether the problem is with yarn or firebase -- they seem to disagree among themselves. But I'll install it as a dev dependency just to shut it up for now. Sigh.

Comment: It would be nice if there were some way to indicate to yarn "I've investigated this, and I _don't_ need that package, so stop warning me about it."

Comment: I'm not affiliated with the Yarn, or Node.js projects, but a quick Google search turned up more questions on SO about this, one of which lead to https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6672 which is about 1 year old and unresolved.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: why is a peer dependency considered "unmet" when it is already satisfied via a transitive dependency?

Comment: How do I see the warnings again on yarn? I got the same errors! @LeeHambley